# What's the difference between using obj-c accessors and using dot syntax?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, macos, accessor

Since I've started on iPhone development I've been kinda confused as to which is the best way to access data as a member in a Class.

Let's say I have a class called MyClass, and in it I have:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    int myInt;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) int myInt;
```

In the implementation, is it better to do this:

```
myObject.myInt = 1;
```

Or this?

```
[myObject setMyInt:1];
```

This goes for reading the value too.

```
int newInt = myObject.myInt;
```

vs.

```
int newInt = [myObject myInt];
```

Comment: Nearly an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249392/ asked just 2 days prior. The answers to that question are more complete and helpful than those here, as well. It would be best to do a more complete search before asking, but 2 questions is better than 0 questions. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't really matter, they are the same thing. The dot syntax is a convenience that's there for you to use, and I feel like it makes your code cleaner.

The one case where I find that using the dot syntax throws warning or errors from the compiler is if you have have an id object, even if you know it has that property.

```
id someReturnedObject = [somethingObject someMysteryObjectAtIndex:5];
int aValue = 0;
aValue = someReturnedObject.value; // warning
aValue = [someReturnedObject value]; // will just do it
```

Answer (score 2):

The type of the object is statically checked with the . syntax, but not with the [] syntax.  This means you can't use . if the object's type isn't specified, and that it is beneficial to use it when it is, so the compiler will help you more.

Answer (score 0):

Dot syntax in Objective-C is essentially shorthand for using the accessor methods. The message is still sent via the accessor method. Hope that answers your question