# Code style: accessing as property

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, properties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Style: Dot notation vs. message notation in Objective-C 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249392/style-dot-notation-vs-message-notation-in-objective-c-2-0)

In apple documentation for NSArray it says: "Instance method>" "count". So, normally I would write `[[NSArray array] count]`. However, `[NSArray array].count` works just fine... And recently I figured out that `UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds` is also accepted. `mainScreen` is a class method for `UIScreen`.

Anyone thought about which style to use (and why)? Please comment.

Comment: +1 for a good question, but voting to close because it is, in fact, a duplicate. More importantly, the answers in the duplicated Q are significantly better.

Comment: @Caleb, You're right, they are. That question should be the first source.

Answer (score 3):

IMO, dot syntax implies a certain passivity; using it shouldn't have significant side effects. It might be okay to treat NSArray's `-count` method as a property even though it isn't actually one (it probably would be if properties had been part of the language when NSArray was created), but saying `someMutableArray.removeLastObject` would offend my sensibilities even though it'd probably work just fine.

One thing you should know about dot notation, though, is that you can't mix Objective-C's dot notation with C's dot notation on the left side of an assignment. In other words, don't try this:

```
myView.bounds.origin.x = 50.
```

You must instead say:

```
CGRect newBounds = myView.bounds;
newBounds.origin.x = 50;
myView.bounds = newBounds;
```

Answer (score 3):

Dot syntax for is just syntactic sugar for calling methods. So `[NSArray array].count` is identical to `[[NSArray array] count]`, and `UIScreen.mainScreen` is identical to `[UIScreen mainScreen]`

You should never use dot syntax for anything other than property access. For property access, the choice is a matter of personal style.

Comment: I think it's fine to use dot notation for methods that act like properties even if they're not declared as properties. NSArray's `count` method is one good example; NSDictionary's `allKeys` and `allValues` are two more.

Comment: @Caleb, I can understand that opinion. I was speaking from an official apple-supported policy perspective. I personally avoid the dot syntax, so it's not really an issue for me.

Comment: I'm not aware of a clear official statement from Apple on this question. Do you know of one? As explained in [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW17), dot syntax is used for accessors, but I don't read that to mean that you have to limit use to properties declared using @property syntax.

Comment: @Caleb, like you said, the docs state the dot syntax is used for accessors, and it defines accessors as "an instance method that gets or sets the value of a property of an object". I interpret that "property" to mean an Objective-C Property, but I suppose you could also interpret it as a reference to the idea of a property, not a specific language feature. Either way, it's incredibly nit-picky, so you're right that your use case is almost certainly acceptable.