# Dot Notation vs Bracket Notation

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Style: Dot notation vs. message notation in Objective-C 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249392/style-dot-notation-vs-message-notation-in-objective-c-2-0)

In objective-C, you can replace bracket notation when sending message with dot notation

[object msg]  becomes object.msg

Is this something I can use interchangeable in most cases, and then keep on chaining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as suggested you can use dot notation only with properties. 
You can also use bracket notation for both properties and normal messages (istance methods) but its a good convention to use the dot notation with properties.

You should really try to get used to the bracket notations, i suppose you come from C/C++ :)
you will get used to very fast, and its not bad at all.

Answer (score 0):

No, the dot notation is for declared properties.