# Objective-C @property and @synthesize best practice

Tags: objective-c, properties, synthesize

So I'm new to Objc-C and I'm just now learning about using `@property` and `@synthesize` for variables and I was wondering how I should then access the variable. Should I access it through `[self var]` or `self.var` or what? This demonstrates my question with code:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *lbl;
...
@synthesize lbl = _lbl;

-(void) doStuff
{
   // How should I acces label?
   _lbl.text = @"A";
   [self lbl].text = @"B";
   self.lbl.text = @"C";
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Style: Dot notation vs. message notation in Objective-C 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249392/style-dot-notation-vs-message-notation-in-objective-c-2-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference here :

```
UILabel * l = [self lbl];  // ==   UILablel *l = self.lbl;
[self setLbl:l];          //  ==   self.lbl = l;
```

But there is a difference here in your sample :

```
_lbl.text = @"A";
```

That last one is not good because you are accessing the iVar directly bypassing your @property, which often don't make sense to do if you have declare it as `@property`.
In your case you are changing a property on your iVar, so there is no harm, but if you would do this :

```
_lbl = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:aRect] autorelease];
```

that would cause you a big problem, because you would have bypass the "setter". A `strong` setter would have retain that object, but now it's retain by no one, it will go away and you will have a bad pointer, that can make your application crash.