# Property access to class methods in Cocoa (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c

You can access class methods of many Apple classes as properties. Example:

```
[UIDevice currentDevice];
UIDevice.currentDevice;
```

Those are the same and both work. How can one implement the same in their classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do something special for the same, it's by default nature but it's always preferable for beginners not to use dot syntax. A proper discussion is in the post below 
[Dot notation vs. message notation for declared properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249392/style-dot-notation-vs-message-notation-in-objective-c-2-0)

Comment: In editors other than Xcode, that doesn't work. You'll get the error: request for member ‘methodName’ in something not a structure or union. That's why I thought otherwise. Thank you.

Comment: I was aware that properties and dot syntax are for accessing state, which is why (in addition to the fact it doesn't work in CodeRunner) I had forgotten that methods could be accessed that way.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything. You can use "dot notation" on any method, whether it was declared by a @property or or by a normal method declaration. That's true for both objects and classes.

Comment: In editors other than Xcode, that doesn't work. You'll get the error: request for member ‘methodName’ in something not a structure or union. That's why I thought otherwise. Thank you.

Comment: By "editors other than Xcode" you mean ["CodeRunner"](http://krillapps.com/coderunner/), then?  Sounds like a bug in CodeRunner.

Comment: +1 Yes, I knew I wouldn't get away with that poor phrasing :)