# How to do a dynamic/computed property in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, properties, xcode5

Having just started doing iPhone programming with iOS 7, I find properties difficult to grasp past the simple. It's difficult to discern what is relevant, and what is no longer relevant as one discovers documentation about them (official or otherwise), since things have evolved over the last few releases.

I get the basic patterns, e.g.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
```

I know I should refer to _name if I want to do direct access, but having done the property, I can/should do `self.name`, and that that will turn into things like `[self setName: ...]` or `[self name]` and that I can even implement these to create side effects, and that I get KVO behavior from them.

The new ground I wanted to venture into today, was having a virtual property, so that I can use dot notation when accessing/setting, but that I will define the access/set methods. More specifically, I have an object with the following "normal" properties:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate* started;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate* paused;
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL repeat;
```

I want to add a `status` property that will return/assign an `NSDictionary` derived from those values. The "methods" part I get how to write:

```
- (NSMutableDictionary*) status {
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    if (self.started != nil)
        dict[@"started"] = self.started;
    if (self.paused != nil)
        dict[@"paused"] = self.paused;
    if (self.repeat)
        dict[@"repeat"] = @(YES);
    return dict;
}
```

and

```
- (void) setStatus: (NSDictionary*) doc {
    self.started = doc[@"started"];
    self.paused = doc[@"paused"];
    self.repeat = doc[@"repeat"] != nil;
}
```

What I don't know, is what magic sauce I add where, so that I can just use `self.status` and `self.status = @{}`? In iOS 7 / Xcode 5. I don't need this virtual/composite property to be KVO'able.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just add

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary* status;
```

to the interface. Since you have implemented both setter and getter for the property,
the compiler with not create any accessor methods (and no backing instance variable
`_status`), and your methods are called.

Comment: But I don't want/need any memory associated with it. I don't need/want a _status ivar magically appearing. Won't this happen if I do as you suggest?

Comment: @TravisGriggs: No (I just added that to the answer). If *both* accessors are implemented, no ivar is created by the compiler for that property.

Comment: So what does trigger the compiler to add the backing variable? How does it discern when to do and not to do that?

Comment: @TravisGriggs: The compiler creates the ivar if not all required accessor methods are provided. For a read-only property: If no getter is provided. For a read-write property: If not both getter and setter are provided.

Comment: OK, lightbulb flickering on I think. Accept imminent. As aside, when *would* I use any of the other special keywords anymore (i.e. dynamic, synthesize, etc)? Or are they all obsolete now?

Comment: @TravisGriggs: You can use `@synthesize prop = _prop;` if you have provided all required accessor methods, but *want* a backing ivar. - And nothing has changed with respect to `@dynamic`. It indicates that the accessors will be provided at *runtime* (for example, Core Data dynamically created accessor methods).

Answer (score 3):

Why not just add a **`property`**:

```
@property NSMutableDictionary *status;
```

You can think of a `property` declaration as being equivalent to declaring two **`dot-accessor`** methods.

There is an ongoing discussion about the merits of `dot notation` vs. `message notation`. You might want to have a look:
[Dot notation vs. message notation for declared properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249392/style-dot-notation-vs-message-notation-in-objective-c-2-0)

Comment: Doing this you implicitly specify `@property (assign, atomic)`.