# self.variableName versus [self variableName]

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've been trying to improve my "Objective-C" programming style, and I came across [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466496/why-rename-synthesized-properties-in-ios-with-leading-underscores) which talks about variables and setting values. It helped me clear up a lot of things, but I still have a question.

Jonathan Sterling mentions in his answer both

```
self.qux = blah;
```

and

```
[self setQux:blah];
```

Is there any difference between the two? If so, which one is the preferred coding style?
And I believe the correct term for the second example is getter and setter methods, but what is the first style called?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249392/dot-notation-vs-message-notation-for-declared-properties?

Comment: Thank you, a great read! I did not know what the different styles were called, so I had a hard time finding something on SO about the subject. This helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are both the same. You can use either of the style of the code. It is called as property. A property has both getter and setter.

For me,

For property, I will use **self.myProperty**.

When it is a method, I will use **[self myMethod];**

It is really depends on your programming style.

Comment: Message passing can be helpful if you have several read-only properties and forget which ones are and aren't. In that case `[self setMyVariable:];` wouldn't appear in Xcode's drop-down list. But of course you'd be shown an error if you use dot notation anyway, so like you've said, it depends on your programming style.