# Confused by message expression and pointer method in Objective c

Tags: objective-c

I have basic Objective c questions.

First look at the following 3 lines.
Second line is getting property using pointer variable(string_ptr)
Third line is a message expression using pointer variable(string_ptr)

```
NSString *string_ptr = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"123"];
string_ptr.absolutePath;
[string_ptr isAbsolutePath];
```

I want to know whether every property can be accessed by '.' (dot) like second line or not?

I also want to know whether any property(not method) can be directly accessed by message expression or not.

I also want to know whether any method can be called with '.' (dot) like c++ function or not.

Because i think i have called some function of some class like following before, But i forgot its example. So i am curious about what is actual difference with message expression and calling method with '.'(dot).

```
obj.aaaamethod;
```

Comment: Strongly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249392/dot-notation-vs-message-notation-for-declared-properties.

Comment: I want to know whether every property can be accessed by '.' (dot) like second line or not? YES

I also want to know whether any property(not method) can be directly accessed by message expression or not. YES (getter== propName, setter= setPropName)

I also want to know whether any method can be called with '.' (dot) like c++ function or not. NO. See: http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/properties